# How to provide context with a generic, but use the context without passing in the generic?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-context, react-typescript

basically, what i want to do is create a context where i pass in a generic like:

in the parent component:

```
const [val, setVal] = useState<ValType>();

<ContextProvider<!ValType!> val={val}>
..children components
</ContextProvider>
```

in one of the child components:

```
const { val } = useContext();
```

here i don't have to pass in the generic and val gets the generic given in the context provider. This is to get intellisense when consuming val.

Is this possible with pure react?

I have tried putting it in a class or a hook (both provider and consumer under the same component), but it did not seem to solve my problem